# How can I decrease the memory usage when upload a big file use Apache2?

Tags: apache, upload

I need to upload files >500M. Apache2 will store it all in memory and then dump to disk. How can let Apache2 write to disk directly?

Comment: What language are you using to manage the upload? PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby?

Comment: PHP, but memory usage of php process is average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what you need to implement is the module buffer, where you can adjust parameters according the I/O filters stack size.

Detailed description here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_buffer.html

and the overview about filters - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/filter.html

for file uploads should exist appropriate modules for apache2 - https://modules.apache.org/

Or maybe its better to upload a big file in chunks...